# How do we deal with constant values with web developing?

Tags: database, json, web

When we develop a web site, we will use the constant values, e.g. the states, cities and the counties, another example is the classifications of blogs. Suppose all these values are constant and we won't change them. The question is how do we store them?

I used to store them in the table of database and now I'm wondering if I can store them in the .json file that will easy to get to show in the front page.

Can anyone give me a routine way to deal with this circumstance?

Comment: I store these in the database, it's fast to read and easy to sort and search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aleks is right that generally the best place is in the database.

You can store them as flat files if they really never change, but it's best to keep everything together in one place.

As a note, I would look into loading the data into a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) so you don't always have to make calls to the database.

The routine way would be:

1. Store in database
2. Make one call to database per structure
3. Keep copy of the one call in memory in your application
4. Refresh as needed